# Delete all items which names start with "old_"

Tags: powershell-extensions

I want to delete all images under the folder Images and all sub-folders too.

This is what I did

```
$path ="master:\sitecore\media library\images"
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse 
ForEach ($item in $$items) 
{
   $item | Remove-Item 
}
```

I need to add a condition to delete all items which their names start with "old_".

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add `Where-Object { $_.Name -like "old_*" }` condition:

```
$path ="master:\sitecore\media library\images"
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "old_*" }
ForEach ($item in $items) 
{
   $item | Remove-Item 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, It worked.

Comment: There is an extra $ character in ForEach loop :)